# jar file built in Android has only META-INF

Tags: android, makefile

I'm build a custom framework for Android device. Here is the makefile:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src) src/com/my_company/my_api/IMyService.aidl
LOCAL_AIDL_INCLUDES := src/com/my_company/my_api/IMyService.aidl
LOCAL_MODULE := com.my_company.mymanager
include $(BUILD_JAVA_LIBRARY)
```

"com.my_company.mymanager.jar" is getting generated. But it has no classes.dex, and it only has "META_INF" directory.

Note: This works well with Android 7.1.1. The issue started to happen after building this with latest Android 7.1.1 changes. Please suggest the reason for this strange behaviour.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Are you solved this issue?